# How to properly use <a> tag with javascript, but no href link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page that has multiple overlays, all triggered by a javascript script with .

It works great, with one exception: the page jumps when you click the link.  I'm aware that I can add an anchor tag for each, and essentially control where it jumps to, but that is not my preference.

I'm also aware that I can use href="javascript:void(0)" to correct this problem, but my group doesn't want javascript:void(0) to show up when a user hovers over the link.

So, what are my options here?  Is there another syntax besides the href="#" I can use in the  tag?

Or is there a way to control the text the browser displays if I use the javascript:void(0) or javascript:null to solve the problem?

Or some other workaround all together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want a link, don't use an A element with an href attribute. Use a span and style it however you want, or use a button.

```js
function whatever() {
  console.log('You clicked me!');
}
```

```css
.linkLike {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<span class="linkLike" onclick="whatever()">Click me</span>
```

Comment: That looks like it works perfectly.  Out of curiosity, is there any way for this to display text in the browser like a link does?

Comment: @Keith—do you mean change colours when visited? You can apply a different class once the element is clicked. If you want it to persist over visits or page refreshes, you'll need to store the history.

Comment: I was referring to the browser "preview" of the url.  For instance, in Chrome if I move my cursor over a link, it shows the purported link destination in the bottom left corner of the browser window.  Is there any way to simulate that action?

Comment: Once upon a time you could use *window.status*, however that was seen as not user friendly so browsers either disable it by default or don't support it at all. You might consider using the [*title*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title) attribute so that a screen hint appears after a short delay.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `e.preventDefault();` in an event handler.

```js
document.getElementById('link').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('click');
});
```

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="link">click</a>
```